# Syntax in Functions (Expected kind `* -> Constraint', but `Int' has kind `*')

Tags: haskell

I'm starting to learn Haskell and I'm struggling with syntax in Functions. I'm trying to create a function that receives a Number 'e' and a Number 'n', returning a list with of 'n' times 'e'.

Example: `repn 3 5` would return `[3,3,3,3,3]`:

```
repn :: Int a => a -> a -> [a]
repn e n
    | n >= 1 = (take n (repeat e))
    | otherwise = []
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
* Expected kind `* -> Constraint', but `Int' has kind `*'
    * In the type signature: replica :: Int a => a -> a
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your type definition is not correct. The double arrow is used to show required typeclasses (aka `kind * -> Constraint`), or a constraint on types. However, `Int` is itself a type (aka `kind *`).

You can't specify types in this way. In your implementation, `n` must be an `Int`, but `e` could be anything. Since you specify that it should be a number, though, you can constrain it with the `Num` typeclass. The correct version of your signature therefore is:

```
repn :: Num a => a -> Int -> [a]
```

If you want `e` to be constrained to an `Int`, then your signature should be

```
repn :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
```

If you don't need any constraints on `e`, your signature can be

```
repn :: a -> Int -> [a]
```

These are all valid type signatures for the function you have written. (Though in actual code, I would just point you to the builtin [`replicate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:replicate) function.)

Answer (score 10):

As a rule of thumb, writing something of the form `Foo a => ...` only makes sense of `Foo` is a *type class*. Unlike in OO languages, a *class* and a *type* in Haskell are completely different things. `Int` is a type, therefore it cannot be used in this way; instead you should simply use

```
repn :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
```

...though actually there's no reason to restrict the list-element type at all, the signature could as well be

```
repn :: a -> Int -> [a]
```

Alternatively, you *can* use a type class: the class of “int-like types” is [`Integral`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Integral). Then you can't use [`take`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:take) directly, as that is restricted to `Int` for the counter argument; however [you can convert](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral) any integral type to `Int`:

```
repn :: Integral n => a -> n -> [a]
repn e n = take (fromIntegral n) $ repeat e
    -- Note no case distinction is needed, because `take` already yields
    -- an empty list if `n<1`.
```